# Matlab loop inside loop

Tags: matlab

I have an Nx2 matrix say D(k1,k2).I have to compare k1 and k2 from each row and switch accordingly. There is another vector d(i) which has M values.
    if k1 and k2 is any one value of d(i) I have to switch.
if  D(k1,1)==d(i)&&D(k1,2)==d(i)....
Is there any method  to compare all the d(i) elements in the if loop without using a for loop for i?

Comment: So if I understand correctly: you want the two elements of a row in the D matrix to switch places, when they both appear in the vector d?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ismember function](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) for checking if the vector d contains certain values:

```
D_in_d = ismember(D,d);
```

and then you still have to loop to perform the flipping operation on specific rows:

```
for i=1:size(D,1)
    if all(D_in_d(i,:))
        D(i,:)=fliplr(D(i,:));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy to accomplish with matlab's vectorizion without any loops at all.

% A swap logical vector ( 1 if you need to swap that row, 0 otherwise)

```
swap_logical = ( ismember(D(:,1),d) | ismember(D(:,2),d) );
```

% Vectorized swapping based on the swap boolian.

```
Dnew = swap_logical.*D(:,2:-1:1) + ~swap_logical.*D;
```

Comment: As ismember already provides logical output I would recommend a simple or statement: `swap_logical = ismember(D(:,1),d) | ismember(D(:,2),d)`

Comment: I agree that is more straight forward.